# Combining rows based on the string in one of the columns

Tags: r

I have the data as below:

```
> dput(test_data)
structure(list(`10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.22123412423, 0.0123915695, 
0.0126915225, 0.4312, 1), `34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.323256312, 
0.32423561, 0.44451256, 0.33623498, 0.21341411, 0.321223), `59` = c(0.232, 
0.57192, 0, 0, 0, 0.31312334, 0.2775713, 0.1311453, 0.63215713, 
0.4423123, 0.132212), `84` = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0), `110` = c(0.55345123, 0.689875, 0.423415551, 1, 0.444532121, 
0, 0.01186404, 0.22132204, 0.21186404, 0, 0), `134` = c(0.234126, 
0.33347267, 0.35321234, 0.4123412, 0.333412666, 0, 0, 0, 0.3123, 
0, 0), `165` = c(0.1147189, 0.12343, 0.3155, 0.2755712, 0.123, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `199` = c(0.1236836, 0.0058933, 0, 0.1344607, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Group = c("Train", "Bicycle", "Car", "Bicycle", 
"Bicycle", "Car", "Bicycle", "Train", "Car", "Train", "Train"
)), .Names = c("10", "34", "59", "84", "110", "134", "165", "199", 
"Group"), row.names = c("Mark_1", "Greg_1", "Tim_1", "Tom_1", 
"Sim_1", "Karl_1", "Moham_1", "Teraq_1", "Jake_1", "Sonya_1", 
"Monique_1"), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to take rows from the same `Group` and combine them into one row. The row.names are not important in that case. As a row name the group should be used. Of course some groups have more members (especially in my real data) so the missing values in specific columns should be filled with `NA's`.

For example values for `Greg`, `Tom`, `Sim`, `Moham` should be in one row under the name `Bicycle`.

Expected output;

We have 4 members of the group `Bicycle`. Each of the member has 8 values = 8 columns. So as an output we should have a row.name=Bicycle and 32 columns with the values coming from those 4 members. We should do the same with all the groups.

EDIT:

So I expected something like `Rechlay` and `Wietze314` posted. Is there any way to remove those `NA` values and keep the number of columns up to maximal number of members multiplied by 8.  I do not care about `colnames` and from which/column value came from.

Comment: I would like to keep `0` values as `0` but I think that in my real data there shouldn't be any `0`. Just all the columns should be taken.

Comment: So, as I mention we take `Bicycle` group. We have 4 members of this group. Each of the member has 8 values = 8 columns. So as an output we should have a `row.name=Bicycle` and 32 columns with the values coming from those 4 members. We can name those columns using the name of the guy who "gave" this value. For example `Greg_1_10`, `Greg_1_34`,....., `Tom_1_10`,..., `Tom_1_110`.

Comment: Seems like some kind of [long to wide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) transformation.

Comment: Could you show the expected output

Comment: As I see I did not explain it correctly. Let me show you the expected output. Need 3 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `tidyr` functions `gather` and `spread`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

result <- test_data %>% mutate(person = row.names(test_data)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Group, -person) %>%
  mutate(column = paste0(person,'_',key)) %>%
  select(column, Group, value) %>%
  spread(column, value)
```

But you will end up with a lot more columns than you anticipate, so maybe you can give us the expected output (as mentioned in the comments).

EDIT:
To get 8 columns per person use:

```
result <- test_data %>% mutate(person = row.names(test_data)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Group, -person) %>%
  group_by(Group, person) %>%
  mutate(column = paste0(person,'_',row_number(key))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(column, Group, value) %>%
  spread(column, value)
```

Finally if you just want 32 columns without caring which value comes from which person you can use:

```
result <- test_data %>% mutate(person = row.names(test_data)) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Group, -person) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>% arrange(person, key) %>%
  mutate(column = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(column, Group, value) %>%
  spread(column, value)
```

To remove NA values from the dataframe use:

```
result[is.na(result)] <- 0
```

Comment: Please take a look on my comment below `akrun's` answer.

Comment: The last one is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps we can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(test_data, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var= c("rn", "Group")), 
           Group~variable + rowid(variable), value.var = "value")
```

#### Update

```
dcast(melt(setDT(test_data, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var= c("rn",
        "Group")), Group+rowid(variable) ~variable, value.var = "value")
```

Comment: Look at my new edit. Is it possible to make a table narrower ? Just store values below each other and extend it to minimum. In this specific case it would be 32 columns. Two rows with 32 columns full of numbers and one row with 24 values and 8 times `NA` at the end of table.

Comment: @ShaxiLiver  I updated the post, but I am not sure whether this is the structure you wanted

Answer (score 0):

```
test_data$row <- row.names(test_data) 
data <- reshape(test_data, idvar= "Group", timevar = "row", direction = "wide")
```

It will give you a long format of your data. The columns will be named as you wanted before an edit.